Great Expectations - Is a checkpoint with varied batch parameters possible?
In Great Expectations, GX Core 1.0+, for its Python API, you know if it is possible for a checkpoint to have varied batch parameters per each gx.ValidationDefinition instance passed to it?
Say, I want every validation definition to be bound to a particular dataframe. But if I pass batch parameters to a gx.Checkpoint(...).run(batch_parameters={"dataframe": df_xyz}) method, it just passes that dataframe to all validation definitions.
How do I work around this? I know you can get a checkpoint per each individual validation definition, but this is something that I would like to avoid as much as possible.

As per Tyler Hoffman in GX Slack:

We discussed that, but for now landed on one
batch parameters dict that gets passed to all validation definitions.
If you want different batch params passed to each validation
definition, I would probably put each in its own checkpoint, and then
pass in the corresponding dataframe to each.

